# ASP.NET view engine won't execute my code snippets

Tags: .net, asp.net, data-binding, webforms

I have an `asp:DataGrid` with templated columns. Here's one of those columns:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDetails"
    Runat="server" 
    CommandName="details" 
    Text="Details"
    Font-Size="0.8em"
    CommandArgument='a=<%# Eval("a")%>&amp;b=<%# Eval("b")%>' />
<...>
```

When the command fires, the `CommandArgument` comes back unevaluated - it is the string `a=<%# Eval("a")%>&b=<%# Eval("b")%>`, not `a=5&b=6` as I want.

What's wrong with how I'm doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah Mitch is correct, if you want another way:

```
CommandArgument='<%# String.Format("a={0}&b={1}",
  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "a"), 
  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "b")) %>'
```

DataBind has to be called, or those substitutions won't happen...

Comment: +1,000,000 I owe you one. I edited the post to make a few syntax corrections.

Answer (score 1):

`<%# Eval() %>` is a databinding expression. You can't concatenate it with another string outside of the eval expression.

Comment: Oh. Is there an alternative that would do what I'm expecting Eval to do?

Comment: one option (not necessarily the best one) would be to create a property on some underlying object "CommandArgument" and evaluate it.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that. Right now I'm simply bound to a DataView that is bound to a stupid StoredProc. Would hate to touch that code...